# exchange 2007 get mailbox size and Issue Warning Quota

Tags: email, powershell, exchange-server

I have Exchange 2007, I get a list of users in TEXT file and I need to get a table like this:

display name   \     mailbox size(MB)    \     Issue Warning Quota(MB)

user1    \                25             \                  40

I wrote those lines:

> > Add-PSSnapin -Name Microsoft.Exchange.Management.PowerShell.Admin
> >
> > > $file=Get-Content c:\mail.txt
> > >
> > > foreach ($mail in $file) {
> > >
> > > Get-MailboxStatistics -Identity $mail | Sort -Property DisplayName |
> > >       ft -AutoSize  DisplayName,
> > >       @{expression={$_.totalitemsize.value.ToMB()};label="Mailbox
> > >       Size(MB)"},|  Out-File c:\mailboxes.txt -Append
>
> }

1) I know that I can'y get "IssueWarningQuota" with this command, I need to use "Get-
   MailBox", I don't know how to add it to the output file.

2) when I run the command in the output file the headers are been duplicate in every user, 
   how can I  avoid that?

Thanks,

Lior

Answer (score 0):

You can use PSObject and Use Export-Csv.

```
Function ConvertStringSizeToInt64{   [CmdletBinding()]
[OutputType([Int64])]
Param ([Parameter(
        Mandatory=$true, 
        Position=0)]
[ValidateNotNull()]
[ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
[string]
$InString
)
Begin
{[Int64]$return = 0}
process 
{   [string]$OutSize = ""
    $InString | Select-String -AllMatches '((?<=\()\d{1,3}|(?<=\,)\d{1,3})' | 
    %{
        $OutSize = ($OutSize+$_.matches.value) -replace " ",""
        $OutSize = [System.Convert]::ToInt64($OutSize)
        $return = $OutSize
    }
}
end
{return $return}
}
# Create Templ Obect
$oT= New-Object psobject
$oT | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name DisplayName -Value $null 
$oT | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name MAilBoxSize -Value $null
$oT | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name IssueWarningQuota -Value $null

Add-PSSnapin -Name Microsoft.Exchange.Management.PowerShell.Admin

$file=Get-Content c:\mail.txt
$R = @()
$file | %{
$T = $oT | select *
$M = Get-Mailbox $_
$T.DisplayName = $M.DisplayName
$T.MAilBoxSize = ConvertStringSizeToInt64 ((Get-MailboxStatistics -Identity $_).totalitemsize)
$T.IssueWarningQuota   =  If ($M.UseDatabaseQuotaDefaults) {ConvertStringSizeToInt64 (Get-MailboxDatabase $M.Database).IssueWarningQuota}
                          Else {ConvertStringSizeToInt64 $M.IssueWarningQuota}
$R +=$T
}
$R | Export-Csv c:\mail.csv
```